# Python: Update Sensor Data to Variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a temperature and pressure gauge that I want to use to track the temperature over time with. Since I may end up with multiple sensors over time, I want to be able to reference my BMP085 sensor as `tp`. In other words, I would like to call `tp.temp` or `tp.pressure` to obtain the current temperature, etc. The problem is that `tp.temp` or `.pressure` is not updating each time I call it. Suggestions?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#temperature logger for the BMP085 Temperature and Pressure Sensor on the Raspberry Pi

from Adafruit_BMP085 import BMP085
from time import sleep
import pickle, sys, os

class tps():
    def __init__(self):
        #temperature/pressure sensor setup
        self.bmp = BMP085(0x77)
        self.temp = self.bmp.readTemperature()*1.8+32
        self.pressure = self.bmp.readPressure()*0.0002953

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tp = tps()
        self.savedata()


    def savedata(self):
#        if os.path.exists("data.dat")==True:
#            if os.path.isfile("data.dat")==True:
#                fileHandle = open ( 'data.dat' )
#                olddata = pickle.load ( fileHandle )
#                fileHandle.close()

        print self.tp.temp, self.tp.pressure
        sleep(4)
        print self.tp.temp, self.tp.pressure

#        newdata = [self.tp.temp, self.tp.pressure]
#        self.datadump = [olddata]
#        self.datadump.append(newdata)
#        fileHandle = open ( 'data.dat', 'w' )
#        pickle.dump ( self.datadump, fileHandle )
#        fileHandle.close()             

data()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you only called the `bmp.readTemperature()` and `bmp.readPressure()` functions once - in `tps.__init__`.  In your print statements at the end, you're just twice reading the values that those functions returned, rather than getting updated values.

Here's an example of how to get updated values:

```
class tps():
    def __init__(self):
        #temperature/pressure sensor setup
        self.bmp = BMP085(0x77)
        self.temp = None
        self.pressure = None
#       If you want to initialize your tps object with sensor data, you can call your updater method here.
        self.updateTempAndPressure()

#   Here's a function that you can call whenever you want updated data from the sensor
    def updateTempAndPressure(self):
        self.temp = self.bmp.readTemperature()*1.8+32
        self.pressure = self.bmp.readPressure()*0.0002953

class data():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tp = tps()
        self.savedata()

    def savedata(self):
#       Call the method that gets updated data from the sensor
        self.tp.updateTempAndPressure()
        print self.tp.temp, self.tp.pressure
        sleep(4)
#       Call the update method again
        self.tp.updateTempAndPressure()
        print self.tp.temp, self.tp.pressure

data()
```